# Why are backslashes and forward slashes not able to be used in passwords

Tags: passwords, password-policy

When making complex passwords *backlashes* and *forward slashes* are often not allowed.

I assume this has to do with errors it probably generates with the db which might not recognize it but I'm not sure.

What is the reason for limiting passwords from using *backlashes* and *forward slashes*

Comment: *"...are generally not allowed"* - this questions is based on a claim without proof. Just to cite from the [password requirements for gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en): *Passwords can contain __any combination of ASCII characters__ and must contain a minimum of 8 characters.*

Comment: What's the reason? Incompetent developers.

Answer (score 1):

The question you have asked is a generic type.
First of let me highlight , backslashes and forward slashes are allowed and have never been restricted when it comes to setting them as passwords.

Let us first understand the history of '/' and '\' , these two are used as escape characters also as path traversal vectors. Keeping this in mind please read the below.

Yes an application that is not configured to escape the '/' and '\' will often lead to login errors. Therefore it is a common practice for applications to validate these characters so that these two are not interpreted as escape characters. Failing to do so will for sure cause login errors. 
Talking about command line utilities like Mysql , if you set a password to let's say 'dee/1p\wa' you can still login by encasing the password in double quotes . 
eg mysql -u root -p "dee/1p\wa" and hence it will be interpreted as one string. however if you do this . mysql -u root -p dee/1p\wa  . then the login will fail .

Overall summary , usage of '/'and '\' in passwords is allowed , it requires the developers effort to ensure that they are validated as string literals and not escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd say generally not allowed - but you're right, they're very commonly restricted.

The issue generally involves anywhere that you may have to pass *text* through an interface - whether it's an SQL query, a commandline, a URL, etc. By far the biggest culprit is database queries. Backslash is used as an escape character, slashes are used in regex, file paths, etc. MySQL even had a documented bug a few years ago where it ignored the backslash in passwords. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69044 such that "abc\def" and "abcdef" would be treated as the same password.

It comes down to a battle of inconveniences. You can address it in several places, but you're mostly just kicking the can down the road to be dealt with somewhere else - or introducing more problems that you didn't expect - like discovering that user passwords that contained a backslash work on the web but aren't accepted in your app because your web developer and your mobile team weren't on the same page with regards to how they were escaping special characters in password strings.

Plenty of developers simply opt for "you may not use slashes in your password or username".

Comment: I don't agree. If they don't allow any type of special character they probably have reasons similar to the one you stated. However, this means their implementation is flawed. Before storing the password in the database, it should be hashed. If they have a problem passing complex passwords from the front to the back-end, they should use an encoding.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't agree with.

"their implementation is flawed." - Obviously!

If you're writing a single web front end that accesses a particular database, you probably don't have this problem. But if we're talking a legacy database with web, mobile, commandline, application front ends, and so on, you really don't get to waltz in and say "everybody should have used an encoding." Sure they should have. They didn't. And there's no budget for you to go through and fix everybody's code just because you want backslashes to be a valid password character.

Comment: I should add: hashed pws in the db is absolutely preferred, but people make bad decisions. In any case, hashing typically happens server-, not client-side, as hash algorithms are most often inconsistent across implementations.

Aside from banning common words, most limits on passwords - what characters can be used, what length they can be, etc, aren't based on best practices in the modern era. I still run into systems that won't let me use more than 8 characters from a limited set. None of that makes sense with proper data handling and modern storage. 100 character unicode pws should be ok.